# RichEditBox FontSize C# windows store app unresponsive

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am trying to give option to user to change font size while entering text in richeditbox.
I have following code:

```
    void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            RichEditBox textBox = sender as RichEditBox;

            ITextSelection selectedText = currentTextBox.Document.Selection;
            if (selectedText != null)
            {
                ITextCharacterFormat charFormatting = selectedText.CharacterFormat;
                charFormatting.Size = (float)textBoxFontSize;
                selectedText.CharacterFormat = charFormatting;
            }                
    }
```

This code is called when  works fine if I use input device as mouse and keyboard.
This code also works if I use touchscreen and put a debug point inside the function mentioned above.

But if I use touchscreen as input device and no breakpoint in the code, the fontsize goes to 10.5 automatically and never changes back.

I see similar issue being faced by others:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/771b6374-37da-4cdd-b68c-7b50b939b775

Comment: have you tried something like this 
`editor.Document.GetRange(0,int.MaxValue).CharacterFormat.Size= aNewFontSize;`

Comment: Hi @DJKRAZE,
added this code from what you mentioned:
`string currentTextBoxText = null;
                textBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out currentTextBoxText);
                int textLength = currentTextBoxText.Length - 1;
                currentTextBox.Document.GetRange(textLength, int.MaxValue).CharacterFormat.Size = (float)textBoxFontSize;`

and it is working.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DJ KRAZE
problem is resolved completely.
Here is the solution which is responsive to mouse-keyboard and touch interactions as well:

```
string currentTextBoxText = null; 
textBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out currentTextBoxText); 
int textLength = currentTextBoxText.Length - 1; 
currentTextBox.Document.GetRange(textLength, int.MaxValue).CharacterFormat.Size = (float)textBoxFontSize;
```